# Creating a Queue Class

Tags: python, queue, deque, enqueue

I am trying to implement a queue class using linked implementation that has the functions enqueue, dequeue, and length. To my understand of queues, when first implemented the queue points to head and tail nodes which initially points to None. As items are added to the queue, a node points to the item, the head node remains unchanged, and the tail node points to the new item.

I've  tried to implement this with the following code in python but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if my logic is wrong, or it's the coding that's wrong, or both?

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        # Initialize this queue, and store data if it exists
        self.data = data
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.node = None
        self.length = 0

    def enqueue(self, data):              
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = Queue(data)
            self.tail = self.head
        else:
            self.node = data
            self.tail = self.node
            data = self.data
        self.length += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        item = self.head.item
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.length -= 1
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
```

Comment: Where are `self.head.item` and `self.head.next` defined? Also, I don't think you need to declare an instance of your class inside of your class methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid declaring an instance of a class inside the definition of a class. Declaring `self.head = Queue(data)` is asking for trouble, in my mind, because that could lead to declarations of `self.head.head`, and `self.head.head.head`... You get the idea. Instead, I would maybe separate things out a bit. Also, notice that you didn't declare `self.head.next` or `self.head.item`, even though you called them in your methods.

Perhaps declare two classes, one for Nodes, and the other for a Queue built out of Nodes? That would simplify things a bit.

Here's how I would build a Queue in Python, credit my own:

```
from typing import Iterable

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __call__(self):
        return self.data

class Queue:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        assert isinstance(x, Node) or (x == None) or isinstance(x, Iterable)
        if isinstance(x, Iterable):
            self.head = Node(x[0])
            self.tail = Node(x[0])
            self.length = 1
            self.to_queue(x[1:])
        else:
            self.head = x
            self.tail = x
            self.length = 1 if x else 0

    def enqueue(self, data):
        tmp = self.head
        self.head = Node(data)
        self.head.next = tmp
        self.length += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.length <= 0:
            print("empty Queue")
            return
        tmp = self.head
        for i in range(self.length-2):
            tmp = tmp.next
        self.tail = tmp
        self.tail.next = None
        self.length -= 1
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None

    def to_queue(self, vals):
        for i in vals:
            self.enqueue(i)

    def __call__(self):
        tmp = self.head
        while (tmp):
            print(tmp.data, end=" ")
            tmp = tmp.next

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
```

Note that this is all unnecessary for production code, as you could just use a `deque`, for example, from the [collections module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to implement the queue as two stacks:

```py
class Stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        if len(self.items) == 0:
            raise IndexError("Can't pop from an empty stack!")
        return self.items.pop(len(self.items) - 1)
    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.items) == 0

class Queue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack1 = Stack()
        self.stack2 = Stack()
    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.stack1.push(item)
    def dequeue(self):
        if self.stack2.isEmpty():
            while not self.stack1.isEmpty():
                self.stack2.push(self.stack1.pop())
        return self.stack2.pop()
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.stack1.isEmpty() and self.stack2.isEmpty()
```

But I agree with the other answers that for any serious project, the standard library and its `collections` module should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could also be implemented this way, I think you failed to define the next Node. Credit not my own.

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

 class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None
        self.rear = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self._size += 1
        node = Node(item)
        if self.rear is None:
            self.front = node
            self.rear = node
    else:
        self.rear.next = node
        self.rear = node

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.front is None:
            raise IndexError("pop from empty queue")
        self._size -= 1
        temp = self.front
        self.front = self.front.next

        if self.front is None:
            self.rear = None
        return temp.data

    def size(self):
        return self._size
```